# What is the purpose of {{ . }} in YAML?

Tags: go, syntax, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I know that {{  }} is used to evaluate expressions. But what does specifically {{ . }} mean in Helm charts?

Example:

```yaml
imagePullSecrets:
      {{- range .Values.image.pullSecrets }}
        - name: {{ . }}
```

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/text/template hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not about YAML, it is about [Go templates](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template).

In Go templates, `{{ }}` evaluates expressions and `.` is the reference to the cursor. In your example, the cursor is set by `range`, which evaluates its body for each element in `pullSecrets`, and in each evaluation the cursor is set to the current element.

Helm uses Go templates to preprocess YAML input. This has nothing to do with YAML itself.